# error about assign List.element

Tags: java, list, arraylist, variable-assignment

```
List<Integer> = New ArrayList<Integer>
//some other code,make sure that the size of list is bigger than 1
System.out.println(list.get(0).getClass().getName()); // print "System.lang.Integer"
list.get(0) = 1;   //this code does't work
```

Why does `list.get(0) = 1` give the following error in `IDE(eclipse)`?

> The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable.

The type of `list.get(0)` is `Integer`, isn't it? `Integer test = 1;` is correct.

Can somebody explain the difference?

Comment: Lets say that we have `Integer get(){ return 1;}`. What should be result of `get() = 2`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot assign to the result of a method call as if it were an array access expression.  The result of the method call `list.get(0)` is a value, not a variable.  This is in contrast to an array access expression, e.g. `array[0]`, which can be treated as a variable and be on the left side of an expression.

The [JLS, Section 15.26](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26), backs this up by stating the only things that can be considered a "variable" on the left side of an assignment operator.

> **The result of the first operand of an assignment operator must be a variable, or a compile-time error occurs**.
>
> This operand may be a named variable, such as a local variable or a field of the current object or class, or it may be a computed variable, as can result from a field access (§15.11) or an array access (§15.10.3).

Instead, use [the `set` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#set-int-E-).

```
list.set(0, 1);  // index, new value
```

Comment: I do use set method to solve this proplem. But why get method return a value, not a variable?

Comment: The `get` method is not special here; it's just like any other method.  All methods return values, except those that are declared to return `void` --  they don't return anything.

Answer (score 1):

list.get(0) is not a variable its a constant. So you need to use set() or add function.